# How to add files to Container element in WiX Burn?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7

I would like to attach a file in [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn). I use following code, but it does not work.

```
<Container Name="Uniqueid.txt" Type="attached"/>
```

I am using WiX 3.7 [RTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_to_manufacturing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Container` creates a container that is filled with assigned package groups.

The container you have declared does not reference any package groups because it has no `PackageGroupRef` children.

---

To designate a file that should be contained, add it as a `Payload` of one of the package elements. If you don't want that package in the default container, create a `PackageGroupRef` that references it and reference that in your `Container` element. Somewhere you must set a `Compressed` attribute that applies to the `Payload` to `yes` (e.g. `Payload` or package).

Comment: Are all the payloads in container cabbed? I want to update files post bundle to inject uniqueness in every file.

Comment: I believe the container storage mechanism is intentionally undefined for WiX 3.6-3.7. I also think that the engine uses a checksum to prevent problems caused by unexpected/missing data.